# What is the degree of $\sqrt[5]{16}$ over Q?

Tags: field-theory

The question is in the title. Obviously I am not looking for the actual degree, just some tips on how to find it.

Eisenstein's criteria doesn't immediately apply to the polynomial $x^5-16$ so I suspect its degree is lower than 5.

Thanks

Comment: I think you might have an error in this question: the degree of a quintic polynomial is, by definition, five. Do you mean the degree of the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: The degree of $x^5 - 16$ is 5. In general the degree of a polynomial is the highest power which has a nonzero coefficient. But I think you mean to ask something else.

Comment: Sorry, that was silly of me. Please check my edit.

Comment: An observation: Consider $(x+1)^5 - 16$; can you apply Eisenstein's criterion to this new polynomial? If so, does that let you draw any conclusions about the initial one?

Comment: Well this new polynomial has a root $\sqrt[5]{16}-1$ and is irreducible by eistenstein's criteria. i'm assuming that tells me that because $\sqrt[5]{16}-1$ is a linear transformation of $\sqrt[5]{16}$ and the former has a degree of 5, the latter must also have a degree of 5. Cool! Thank you!

Comment: the roots of $x^5-16$ have absolute value $2^{4/5}$. If the polynomial is reducible, say if something of degree $k$ divides it, then the absolute coefficient of this dividing polynomial has absolute value $2^{4k/5}$, and that's not a rational number. So it is irreducible over rationals and the degree is thus $5$.